# Is there any use of making an array final (immutable) in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object-oriented-analysis

Is there any reason why one would declare a array final?
say something like this

```
final int[] array={1,2,33,21,11};
```

Comment: Just because the array is final does not mean that it is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It provides an invariant that the assignment of 'array' can't be changed.  (When looking at code I can assume 'array' won't get reassigned).  However nothing stops an element from being changed.  Ex. array[2] can be changed from 33 to 25.

Answer (score 9):

There may be several. At least, it ensures that

- later code cannot point the variable 'array' to another array
- the variable 'array' can be seen by anonymous inner classes (e.g. listeners).

Importantly, it does *not* ensure that the contents of 'array' are immutable.

Comment: '...seen by anonymous inner classes'; good point; these must be final otherwise the compiler will reject

Answer (score 0):

The reasons are the same as with any other mutable type: the reference stays the same throughout the lifecycle of the declaring object, so you can distribute it freely for example. `final` is always about the reference being fixed and not the contents, which might change.

With arrays, you even get a guarantee that the array size isn't going to change, although how useful that guarantee is depends on the specific use case.

Comment: It's true that the array size will be locked but nothing prevents array elements from being changed; therefore we can't consider it immutable.  It won't be automatically safe to pass among multiple threads.

Comment: As I said: _The reasons are the same as with any other **mutable** type_. I wish you pointed out where you think I said it made the array immutable.

Comment: @bizicop sorry I misread your comment.  final arrays are indeed mutable :)

Comment: @seand Fair enough, if one person misread it, others might too. I added some clarification to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only declare the array *reference* final, which has nothing to do with making the array immutable. Arrays are never immutable in Java.